# OSX: start app with runtime-dependent dylibs

Tags: macos, runtime, rpath

OSX 10.10 Yosemite.
My application depends on Intel IPP. 
At compile time it depends on 2 dylibs, but these depend from other dylibs, which **are loaded at runtime** (and not displayed in otool -L) . When starting my application does not find these libraries.

I do not understand how can I specify for my app (or for the compile time dependent dylibs) **a folder to search a path for runtime dylibs**.

As far as I can understand, it is necessary to use rpath. But what exactly should be done? How to set runtime search path? Do I need to set a 'rpath' for the executable file or for the dylibs?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to use `install_name_tool` command to add the dylib.

Don't think you can setup a folder that can magically load all the dylib in it. It's against the purpose of code signing and security.

Comment: runtime loaded libs are not displayed in otool. And a composition of runtime libraries also depends on the processor